# Finding the frequency of substring from a string

Tags: java, android, string, intellij-idea, frequency

I am trying to find the frequency of occurrence of substring in a string. 
For example:

String is: House Dog Bat Dog House Dog Bat

The result should be:

**In first iteration:**

House=2 Dog =3 Bat=2

**In second iteration:** 
House Dog

Dog Bat

Bat Dog

Dog House

House Dog

Dog Bat

So both House Dog and Dog Bat will have a frequency of 2 and others 1

**In third iteration:**

House Dog Bat

Dog Bat Dog

Bat Dog House

Dog House Dog

House Dog Bat

Dog Bat

Bat

Only House Dog Bat will have a frequency of 2. Others will be 1.

And the counting process continues until particular number of iterations?

Have to implement it in IntelliJ Idea Android but Java code will be helpful as well.

Have searched the web already.

And yes the input will always be different and long.Input will be google search result source code. Dogs and houses were just for example.

Current code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

 Map<String, Integer> unique = new LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>();
    for (String string : "House House House Dog Dog Dog Dog".split(" ")) {
        if(unique.get(string) == null)
            unique.put(string, 1);
        else
            unique.put(string, unique.get(string) + 1);
    }
    String uniqueString = join(unique.keySet(), ", ");
    List<Integer> value = new ArrayList<Integer>(unique.values());

    System.out.println("Output = " + uniqueString);
    System.out.println("Values = " + value);

}

   public static String join(Collection<String> s, String delimiter) {
       StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
       Iterator<String> iter = s.iterator();
       while (iter.hasNext()) {
             buffer.append(iter.next());
               if (iter.hasNext()) {
               buffer.append(delimiter);
               }
       }
       return buffer.toString();
     }
```

Comment: Split the string on the space character. For each word increment a variable (counter for that word).

Comment: I know I have to split it on space. It's the second iteration and so on on which I am having problem.

Comment: Current code added in the edit

Comment: You might add the information that with each "iteration" you are searching for a substring that consists of one more word respectively. In first iteration you're looking for substrings of one word each, in second iteration for substrings of two words each and so on.

Comment: @HubertGrzeskowiak Exactly. Basically I am making an android App.After scanning a barcode of a product I need it's name. So i will be sending that barcode as search on google and apply the above algorithm on the result set. 
The result set will be limited to between some particular tags. Do you think the above algo will work in what I am trying to achive?

Comment: The whole question has nothing to do with Android, Google or IntelliJ Idea, but just basic Java SE.

Comment: @HubertGrzeskowiak I was just asking about the logic. Anyways, can you help me with the code?

Comment: Sorry, no time right now. Also SO is not about other people coding for you. Just google for "java bigrams" or something like that. Other than that you might want to look into the String.indexOf(String, int) function, which finds whole substrings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution which I was able to develop. Method of Join is written in my question.

```
    public static void getStringTripple(String a){      
          String s[]=a.split(" ");
          List<String> asList = Arrays.asList(s);
          Map<String, Integer> unique = new LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>();
          String string="";
       for(int i=0;i<asList.size();i++){
       for(int j=i;j<s.length;j++){
           string+= asList.get(j);
         if(unique.get(string) == null)
            unique.put(string, 1);
        else
            unique.put(string, unique.get(string) + 1);
          }
       string="";
    }
    String uniqueString = join(unique.keySet(), ", ");
    List<Integer> value = new ArrayList<Integer>(unique.values());


    System.out.println("Output = " + uniqueString);
    System.out.println("Values = " + value);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this to search repeation of word

```
public static void getStringTripple(String a){      
        String s[]=a.split(" ");
        List<String> asList = Arrays.asList(s);
        Set<String> mySet = new HashSet<String>(asList);
        for(String ss: mySet){
            if(Collections.frequency(asList,ss)>=3)
                System.out.println(ss + " " +Collections.frequency(asList,ss));
        }       
    }
```

Comment: I think he has more problems with finding repetitions of strings consisting of multiple words.